# Is there a way to autoformat code in Android Studio?

Tags: java, android, android-studio, format

I have been coding for a while in Visual Studio with visual basic and there was an option to autoformat code at the same time you were coding.

I know i can format it in Android Studio with CTRL+ALT+L but is there any option so the software do it automatically?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

You can't, you must do t 'manually' with the macro, the closer option is maybe to map the macro on ctrl+s to save and format at the same time.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, it's possible. There's an IntelliJ plugin called save actions that will allow you to do this.

https://plugins.jetbrains.com/plugin/7642-save-actions

instructions (plus more) here https://jivimberg.io/blog/2018/06/10/intellij-idea-tips/